# Finding equations of two tangent lines

Tags: calculus

I have a prolate cycloid: 
$$\begin{align*}
x &= 2 - \pi\cos(t)\\  
y &= 2t - \pi\sin(t)
\end{align*}$$
over the interval $-\pi \leq t \leq \pi$,
crossed itself at point $P$ on the $x$-axis

a) Find the equations of the 2 tangent lines at $P$

b) find the points on curve where tangent line is *horizontal*.

c) find the point on curve where tangent line is *vertical*.

So I know for part $b$ and $c$, you just need to use the derivatives $dx$ and $dy$ and then solve for when $dx=0$ and $dy=0$... however for part a), do I just simply take the derivative of both $x$ and $y$ and that is my solution?

Comment: Why is the answer not accepted?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Because the person asking the question never accepted it; and he has not been on the site since August 2012.

Comment: Something should be done in this case, right? So people are not mislead thinking this question is unanswered, even though it has a good answer.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: No, "something" need not be done. This question is not "unanswered", as it has an answer with upvotes. It does not have an accepted answer, but that is different from being "unanswered". That's not how the site works. Only the person who asks the question can "accept" an answer. Acceptance only reflects that the person who posed the question is satisfied with the given answer.

Comment: @Arturo I'm making the case for us not being able to determine if the person is satisfied with the answer since he/she hasn't been of the site since roughly seven years and isn't likely to return and tell us. Maybe he just forgot to accept...

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Discussions about the site should take place in the [meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/), not in comments to questions in the main site. You are making the wrong argument in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $dx$ is not a derivative, it's a differential. Same with $dy$.

What you mean, presumably, is that you will take $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ for parts (b) and (c). Note that 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\quad\frac{dy}{dt}\quad}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$
so you can use this for (a), (b), and (c). For (a), this can be used to get the *slope* of the tangent, but to find the *equation* of the tangent you'll have to do a bit more work. For (b), you want $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be $0$, so you want $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}\neq 0$. For (c), you want $\frac{dy}{dt}\neq 0$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$.

Comment: Alright, so I think I got part b and c down alright.. but for part a, i solved for dy/dx and I get (2-picos(t))/(pisin(t))... but not sure what the next step is to find the EQN of the tangent?

Comment: @Nick: If you know the point and you know the slope(s), you should be able to get the equation.